# Include grails tag in assets image

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-3.1

I am trying to include grails render tag inside assets image title, but getting an error like

```
<asset:image src="layout/bell.png" title='<g:render template="/srcdir/incompletePage" model="[dataObj: names]"/>' />



org.grails.taglib.GrailsTagException: [grails-app\views\abc.gsp:302] Attribute value quote wasn't closed (src="layout/bell.png" title='<g:render template="/srcdir/incompletePage" model="[dataObj: names]")
```

is there any other way to add the render template?

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not pretty, you should be able to achieve what you want 
by using the tag as a method call:

```
<asset:image src="layout/bell.png" title='${g.render( template:"/srcdir/incompletePage", model:"[dataObj: names]"}' />
```